# Uniqueness continuity equation optimal transport (using transport equation)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, distribution-theory, optimal-transport

In the following
$\mu: [0,1] \to P_2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a curve in space of probability measures having finite second moment in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $v:[0,1] \times \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ is a vector field.
The continuity equation is
$$
\partial_t \mu_t + \nabla\cdot (\mu_t v_t) =0 \\
\mu(0)=\mu_0
$$
in the sense of distribution.

Suppose that the for every $T>0$ and $\psi: \mathbb{R}^+ \times\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ the transport equation TE admits a solution $f$, where TE is
$$
\frac{d}{dt} f+ v\cdot \nabla f = \psi \\
f(T,\cdot)=0
$$

Then prove that the continuity equation admits at most one absolutely continuous solution in the sense of distribution.

I do not know where to start, I wrote the continuity equation as the condition $ \forall \phi \in C_c^\infty (\mathbb{R}^d) $
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int \phi \, d\mu_t = \int \nabla \phi\, \cdot v_t d\mu_t
$$
and try to think of a smart choice of $\psi$ to get something interesting, but had no ideas. Any help?

Comment: Try as testfuction a solution of the TE.

Comment: Test functions may also depend on $t$.

Comment: What you should show is that if $f$ and $g$ both satisfy the TE with given initial conditions then $f=g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really a PDE guy, so I'm deliberately neglecting regularity issues. Yet, I guess a rigorous proof will rely on an argument as follows:
Assume there is another solution to the CE, say $\mu'$. Then by linearity the difference $\nu=\mu-\mu'$ also satisfies CE, but with $\nu(0)=0$. Now let $f$ be a solution to TE. Then
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\int f_{t}d\nu_{t}=\int(\dot{f_{t}}+\nabla f_{t}\cdot v_{t})d\nu_{t}=\int\psi d\nu_{t}.
\end{equation}
Integrate from $0$ to $T$ you observe that
\begin{equation}
0=\int_{0}^{T}\int\psi d\nu_{t}.
\end{equation}
This being true for all $T>0$ and $\psi$ should imply $\nu\equiv 0$ which yields the claim.